# Setting div's style to "none" or "block" using javascript doesn't work in IE9, but it works in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a form that I'm putting on a webpage, and most of my users will be using IE. There's a series of radio buttons at the top, and when any of them are selected, the form below should change. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function prepareForm() {
  var t = document.getElementById('top');
  document.getElementById('search1').style.top = t.style.top + t.style.height;
  document.getElementById('search2').style.top = t.style.top + t.style.height;
  document.getElementById('search3').style.top = t.style.top + t.style.height;
}
function displayForm() {
  var a = document.getElementsByName('search');
  var b = document.getElementsByName('searchBy');
  for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    if (!b[i].checked) {
      a[i].style.display="none";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display="block";
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
    <body style="font-family:calibri;text-align:center;" onLoad="displayForm();">
<div id="top">
<center><h3>My webpage</h3></center>
<br>
<form method="post" action="results.html" name='myForm'>
<center><font face='calibri'>Search By:</center><br>
<center>
<input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="search1" checked onClick="displayForm();">Form one
<input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="search2" onClick="displayForm();">Form two
<input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="search3" onClick="displayForm();">Form three
</div>

<!-- search area 1 -->
<div name="search" id="search1" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;">
<p>Form 1</p>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</div>

<!-- search area 2-->
<div name="search" id="search2" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:none;">
<p>Form 2</p>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit"></b>
</div>

<!-- search area 3 -->
<div name="search" id="geoSearch" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:none;">
<p>Form 3</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code appears to work in Chrome, but in IE9, the displayed  doesn't change when the javascript function `displayForm()` is called. Is there something about a div's `style.display` attribute that's different between IE9 and Chrome?

Comment: [note] attribute `language` for script is deprecated.

Comment: @Mr_Green attribute `language` for scripts is deprecated in HTML5 ;)

Comment: @mdesdev yeah I am not talking about old HTML4 or HTML3 :P

Comment: `language` attribute is obsolete from HTML 4. XHTML is an XML serialisation of either HTML 4 or HTML 5.

Comment: I didn't know that `language` attribute is obsolete from HTML 4, thanks for the info ;)

Comment: the values like `style.top` and `style.height` are coming with `px` so this I am sure will not work in any browser. maybe it will work for first time but not every time.

Comment: @Mr_Green it works every time in Chrome, but never in IE9.

Comment: Is this code copy-pasted from 2004 ? If you truely need help, start by searching about why IE bugs with document.getElementByID .. https://www.google.ca/#q=document.getElementById+ie+bug  **this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the ID and NAME attributes, which might produce unexpected results.**

Answer (score 0):

If you truely need help, start by searching about why [IE bugs with document.getElementByID](https://www.google.ca/#q=document.getElementById+ie+bug)

From : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx :

> this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the ID and NAME
>   attributes, which might produce unexpected results.

After reading some about it, validating over a `<!doctype>`, try replacing your 'name' and 'id' so they match then test it and come back here with details and more infos so WE can try to help you further more.

PostScriptum : when i read this : "I didn't know that language attribute is obsolete from HTML 4" it felt like **dang! Am i waisting my time trying to help someone who will never grow in a web UI development career, didn't do his homework with all his heart, and is most likely to become a 'copy-paster'** coming on Stackoverflow to ask for '*do this because i can't*'.

Comment: The bug does not appear to be with document.getElementById(). This code:

Comment: The bug does not appear to be with document.getElementById(). This code:

    var a = document.getElementsByName('search');
    var b = document.getElementsByName('searchBy');

appears to give two different numbers for a and b (in my example, both should be equal to 3). In IE, a=0 and b=3, while in Chrome, a=b=3, which is what I would have expected. "Name" does not appear to be a valid attribute in a <div> element. I found another way to do it.

Comment: By : "I found another way to do it"  you mean, you fixed your issue and this question is about to be deleted ?